# Slicing nested list by index in python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a nested list with unequal length:
`[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8]]` and I have a `start_index=(i,j)` and `end_index=(a,b)` and I need to print all elements between `start_index` and `end_index`. For example if `start_index=(1,1)` and `end_index=(2,2)` then I will print `(5,6,7,8)`

Comment: I wonder if it would be simpler to return `[[5], [6, 7, 8]]` then flatten it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
def nested_index(arr, start, end):
    res = arr[start[0]][start[1]:]
    for i in range(start[0] + 1, end[0]):
        res.extend(arr[i])
    res.extend(arr[end[0]][:end[1] + 1])
    return res

>>> print(nested_index([[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8]], (1, 1), (2, 2)))
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```